# no data populating firebase realtime database Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-viewbinding

I'm new to coding and have recently attempted to learn Kotlin. I'm currently attempting to insert data into the firebase database via 2 editTexts and a save button. I have created a data class, a function, and incorporated viewBinding. I have confirmed the firebase url is correct in my json file and checked dependencies. I've also added 2 lines to my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I've been through dozens of videos, articles, stackoverflow questions, and I still can't figure out what I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package com.example.firebase_test2

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.firebase_test2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.firebase_test2.extensions.closeKeyboard
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var dbRef: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // initializing database
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://fir-test-74993-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com").reference

        binding.SaveButton.setOnClickListener {
            fbdb()
        }

        //closeKeyboard
        binding.ConstraintMain.setOnClickListener {
            closeKeyboard()
        }
    }

    private fun fbdb() {

        val etTechName = binding.techNameEditText2.text.toString()
        val etMODName = binding.modNameEditText2.text.toString()

        val myKey = dbRef.push().key!!
        val dbModel = Packages(myKey, etTechName, etMODName)

        dbRef.child(myKey).setValue(dbModel)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data inserted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                binding.techNameEditText2.text?.clear()
                binding.modNameEditText2.text?.clear()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { err ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + err.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }


}
```

```
package com.example.firebase_test2

data class Packages(val myKey: String? = null, val techName: String? = null, val modName: String? = null,){

}
```

```
--------- beginning of system
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (26097) for package com.example.firebase_test2 ----------------------------
2022-11-06 23:41:09.598   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~0TgmmMPToOp04wiMUFhjRA==/com.example.firebase_test2-dJ9ia1ScqWdc9IpKYonU8w==/base.apk
2022-11-06 23:41:11.816   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~0TgmmMPToOp04wiMUFhjRA==/com.example.firebase_test2-dJ9ia1ScqWdc9IpKYonU8w==/base.apk
2022-11-07 20:07:41.616   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~Vskdn68kH_Xb2p8VrKybwQ==/com.example.firebase_test2-hBirHeVU63cDghyN3oXMyQ==/base.apk
2022-11-07 20:07:42.329   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~Vskdn68kH_Xb2p8VrKybwQ==/com.example.firebase_test2-hBirHeVU63cDghyN3oXMyQ==/base.apk
--------- beginning of main
2022-11-07 20:08:03.315  7556-7556  studio.deploy           pid-7556                             E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-07 20:17:28.172  7556-7556  studio.deploy           pid-7556                             E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-07 20:18:36.626  7556-7556  studio.deploy           pid-7556                             E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-07 20:19:18.759  7556-7556  studio.deploy           pid-7556                             E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-07 20:24:45.394  7556-7556  studio.deploy           pid-7556                             E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-07 20:34:27.337   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~McuFoKBMTGZsV8ze4AYSxA==/com.example.firebase_test2-TxfKzo-05X3QHCzJaJ8pUw==/base.apk
2022-11-07 20:34:27.623   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~McuFoKBMTGZsV8ze4AYSxA==/com.example.firebase_test2-TxfKzo-05X3QHCzJaJ8pUw==/base.apk
2022-11-07 20:35:27.493  8937-8937  studio.deploy           pid-8937                             E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-07 20:36:22.566   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~KMqhboALV-4pfyjFnxyJTg==/com.example.firebase_test2-jAbPnuL5hs-YWIIt1T941w==/base.apk
2022-11-07 20:36:22.864   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~KMqhboALV-4pfyjFnxyJTg==/com.example.firebase_test2-jAbPnuL5hs-YWIIt1T941w==/base.apk
2022-11-07 20:37:27.036  9188-9188  studio.deploy           pid-9188                             E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 15:30:57.669  9890-9890  studio.deploy           pid-9890                             E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 15:31:28.348  9890-9890  studio.deploy           pid-9890                             E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 15:33:05.456  9890-9890  studio.deploy           pid-9890                             E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 16:05:39.979   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~FfxBbz3JksmVAvSsU6g11A==/com.example.firebase_test2-ibsDlXm97mXhIIufuwLb5w==/base.apk
2022-11-08 16:05:40.614   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~FfxBbz3JksmVAvSsU6g11A==/com.example.firebase_test2-ibsDlXm97mXhIIufuwLb5w==/base.apk
2022-11-08 16:06:46.363   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~dqEZRiElyI5c0DrSOjZRTg==/com.example.firebase_test2-irQ_dmXvxlMLiy5uKA3v2A==/base.apk
2022-11-08 16:06:46.478   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~dqEZRiElyI5c0DrSOjZRTg==/com.example.firebase_test2-irQ_dmXvxlMLiy5uKA3v2A==/base.apk
2022-11-08 16:07:54.210   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~8ZYz0_jy2zB67OfA32O6Tg==/com.example.firebase_test2-xO24zqmBxNHNSLIzFnVwag==/base.apk
2022-11-08 16:07:54.552   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~8ZYz0_jy2zB67OfA32O6Tg==/com.example.firebase_test2-xO24zqmBxNHNSLIzFnVwag==/base.apk
2022-11-08 16:09:15.426   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~q0NbsVPO9za7BsQJmyFdRg==/com.example.firebase_test2-AiuVW_JIaicTFgYCZO6S2w==/base.apk
2022-11-08 16:09:15.576   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~q0NbsVPO9za7BsQJmyFdRg==/com.example.firebase_test2-AiuVW_JIaicTFgYCZO6S2w==/base.apk
2022-11-08 16:51:52.155   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~LOP8bpDowikMIZgaS8b7cA==/com.example.firebase_test2-sMcODTMP-9DT1nNngor50g==/base.apk
2022-11-08 16:51:52.910   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~LOP8bpDowikMIZgaS8b7cA==/com.example.firebase_test2-sMcODTMP-9DT1nNngor50g==/base.apk
2022-11-08 17:28:45.522 14680-14680 studio.deploy           pid-14680                            E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 17:28:49.803 14680-14680 studio.deploy           pid-14680                            E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 17:34:31.544   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~3xlEIGEqtOzGertZP2gRDw==/com.example.firebase_test2-rFKPpRb8x_5cSF2nSVsaOQ==/base.apk
2022-11-08 17:34:32.212   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~3xlEIGEqtOzGertZP2gRDw==/com.example.firebase_test2-rFKPpRb8x_5cSF2nSVsaOQ==/base.apk
2022-11-08 17:36:38.146 15578-15578 studio.deploy           pid-15578                            E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 22:22:38.147   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~p_nuoiwuZccVZYdUWhJ5Qw==/com.example.firebase_test2-hSasbxt8GpaPs_RW7yJhJg==/base.apk
2022-11-08 22:22:38.444   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~p_nuoiwuZccVZYdUWhJ5Qw==/com.example.firebase_test2-hSasbxt8GpaPs_RW7yJhJg==/base.apk
2022-11-08 22:25:24.206 20127-20127 studio.deploy           pid-20127                            E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 22:27:46.665 20127-20127 studio.deploy           pid-20127                            E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 22:40:43.183   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~TG_GPezq7XZxmdWKsblw-Q==/com.example.firebase_test2-e7G5gITP777lk9F0sa2RdQ==/base.apk
2022-11-08 22:40:43.369   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~TG_GPezq7XZxmdWKsblw-Q==/com.example.firebase_test2-e7G5gITP777lk9F0sa2RdQ==/base.apk
2022-11-08 22:42:17.873 21385-21385 studio.deploy           pid-21385                            E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 22:47:12.622 21385-21385 studio.deploy           pid-21385                            E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 23:03:52.034 21385-21385 studio.deploy           pid-21385                            E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 23:07:41.846 21385-21385 studio.deploy           pid-21385                            E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 23:12:23.191 21385-21385 studio.deploy           pid-21385                            E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-08 23:22:20.693 21385-21385 studio.deploy           pid-21385                            E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.firebase_test2/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-11-09 14:41:14.348   589-637   VerityUtils             pid-589                              E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~qW1ReSyUuCWog9qSOvYU9A==/com.example.firebase_test2-OHmu08Pot5crKOwHogH-sw==/base.apk
```

Comment: I don't see that you've shown any code that writes data or any error messages taht suggests what's wrong.  What is `fbdb()`?

Comment: it should be written in as a function which would be where the addOnCompleteListener and .addOnFailureListener are.

Comment: Is any of the toast messages displayed? If yes, which one? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo no toast messages are displaying either. When I click on the Save button, I don't see anything happening.

Comment: @AlexMamo additionally, I attempted to create a function to use as a test. I read that if things are set up correctly, something like this should add a "hello world" message in the database but this did not work either.

private fun dbTest() {
        val key = dbRef.push().key!!

        dbRef.child(key).child("message").setValue("Hello World")
    }

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the Logcat data to my question in the final code block. I'm not super sure how to decipher this. lol

Comment: If none of the listeners fires, then are you sure you're connected to the internet?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes. Network connection is fine. Am I correct in assuming my code looks correct based on your question? Could it possibly be that it wont run in the android simulator?